# strtotime wont convert this 2014-06-03T07:00:00.000Z

Tags: php

I have the following sting

```
2014-06-03T07:00:00.000Z
```

I want to convert it on fly like

```
strtotime("Y-m-d h:i",2014-06-03T07:00:00.000Z");
```

but that doesnt work... what can I do to convert time in the above format easily?

Comment: [It doesn’t take a format argument.](https://php.net/strtotime) You may be thinking of `DateTime::createFromFormat` or `strptime`. (That’s still not the right format string, though.)

Comment: might be a typo, looks like you are missing a "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using **[strtotime()](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.strtotime.php)** incorrectly - it returns a timestamp, not a formatted date. You need to use it in conjunction with **[date()](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.date.php)**, which will return a formatted date based on a given timestamp:

```
$date = "2014-06-03T07:00:00.000Z";
echo date("Y-m-d h:i", strtotime($date));
```

[**See demo**](http://codepad.org/dMBJsxlK)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, what you want is this:

```
date("Y-m-d h:i", strtotime("2014-06-03T07:00:00.000Z"));
```

Let me mention, however, that your example is also malformed -- you are missing a quote mark at the beginning of your input string.

```
strtotime("Y-m-d h:i",2014-06-03T07:00:00.000Z"); 
                      ^missing a " right there
```

Now let me tell you what the problem was:

The `strtotime` function optionally expects a relative date (as described [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php)), for instance `"+2 days"`, and a time, and returns a UNIX timestamp (which may look something like `1401778800`). `strtotime` does not format that date for you. So you use `strtotime` to get a timestamp.

Once you have a timestamp, you can format it with the `date` function, which takes a format string and a timestamp.

In order to convert from one date format to another in PHP, you will need to use `date` and `strtotime` together to create a timestamp, and then format it.